# How to run a self-testing on an email applied with schema markup using sub domain (alias)?

Tags: email, subdomain, google-schemas

1. Applied Go-to-action > View action Schema Microdata code in my emails.
2. Tested and verified the code on https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/.
3. Performed every step that https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema asks to do.
4. Tried self-testing the schema applied email using my primarily used sub-domain alias, say, abc@tuv.xyz.com, but couldn't see the action box appearing.

It'd be great if someone could enlighten me on the application of schema in my transactional emails send via sub-domain (aliases).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot use a sub-domain alias in sending schema applied emails. Check the [Email Sender Quality guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#email_sender_quality_guidelines) wherein it stated that emails must come from a static email address, e.g. foo@bar.com.